# URL Rewriting and actual directory names matched by regex

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I created an application using the `Front Controller` pattern, so basically everything is sent to `index.php`

This is what I currently have in my `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(\/([a-zA-Z0-9]+))?(\/([a-zA-Z0-9\/]+))?(\/)?$   
                   index.php?class=$1&method=$3&args=$5
```

(I had to break the line into two, for presentation but you know what I mean)

So it works fine however if I create a directory named `/js` for example that has to be directly accessible. That means, I can't put an `.htaccess` file inside it and put:

```
Deny from all
```

Then accessing my site using the URL `http://mysite.com/js` redirects to `http://mysite.com/js/?class=js&method=foo&args=`

Putting `Options -Indexes` in the main `.htaccess` file doesn't really help. Any thoughts?

Any clarifications are welcome, I'm not really an good at explaining things.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Exclude real files and directories from the redirection rule (redirection rule will not apply to the real files and directories).